# Update UI element from a different class running in background thread

Tags: c#, multithreading, class, ftp, backgroundworker

I run into a dead end in my project. I am running a BackgroundWorker *(in a class FTPcllient)* in my Form1 that starts up a FTP file download function (called download) in a different class *(Called FTPengine)* like this.

*(I run this naturally in a background thread so the UI dont get stuck when something big is downloading from FTP.)*

```
private void download_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    ftp ftpClient = new ftp(parameters[0], parameters[1], parameters[2]); //Init connection
    ftpClient.download(file, localfile); //Start download
}
```

And I have a function called "Report progress" *(in a FTPengine class)* that return a two integers (a file size in bytes and a current downloaded bytes). I need to get this two integers back to a UI thread and report the progress into a ProgressBar element.

I tried multiple time using the invoke methods and Backgroundworker reportprogress but since the code is actually not directly in the backgroundworker but in the totally different class I had no luck. Isearched the web and many more but with no result. If somebody have some idea what changes needs to be made, it would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

If you can access to Dispatcher, you can call

```
Dispatcher.RunAsync(priority,()=>
{
  //The Action with the parameters
});
```

Depending on the version the method changes

In case you do not have access in that place you can use App.RootFrame.Dispatcher or Window.Current.Dispatcher all depends on the version of app you are creating.

ADDED

In the case of Windows Forms

```
BeginInvoke((Action)(() =>
        {
            //Do what you need
        }));
```

and there process what you need in the UI

Comment: Hello Juan, thank you for the fast response. Can you please post any particullar example of using your suggestions ? If I want to use the dispatcher I end up with a bunch of errors (...The name 'Dispatcher' does not exist in the current context etc.)

Comment: A normal Windows Forms application. (FTPcllient)
and Class Library (FTPengine).
Thank you.